# Generalized Android Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am new to Android programming. My question is that i have a list (ListView) of 8 restaurant headings. Upon clicking of any of these, a new page (activity) would start containing the menu and details of the restaurant. I understand that implementing 8 activities would be wasteful so probably i will have a general restaurant detail activity.

Now i am figuring out how to display this information out in an efficient way. I have so far implemented this which helps me to send a message across to the other activity according to the restaurant selected. But how can i send big chunks of information:

**----MainActivity.java------**

```
String [] restaurants = {"abc","def"....};
int POSITION_ACT;           

list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
            POSITION_ACT=position;
            customActivity(view);
           }
    });

public void customActivity(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RestaurantDetails.class);
    intent.putExtra(MESSAGE, "You clicked this restaurant: " + restaurants[POSITION_ACT]);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**--generalrestaurant.java----**

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String msg = intent.getStringExtra(foodActivity.MESSAGE);
    TextView tt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tt1);

    tt1.setText(msg);
```

Comment: define `big chunks of information`

Comment: Restaurant should be an object with all of the relevant information that you need (Serializable). Pass that through the intent.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be passing lots of information. Your model information should be in instances of a Restaurant class. Then you can keep all those instances in an ArrayList in a singleton. Write a getter for the singleton that returns a Restaurant instance and then call it from the RestaurantDetails activity using the extra you sent (maybe you want to make this a UUID). Finally, when the activity dies, you should save the Restaurant data from the singleton to a raw XML file or something and read it back in when the app starts up again.

Comment: Passing it as a serializable object like the others suggested would also work, but I like to use my suggested method because it helps you stick to an MVC design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **POJO** for your restaurant information and write data like Name, Location, Per head cost, rating etc to it. Then your POJO must implement `Serializable` or `Parcelable`. In your intent you can pass your POJO using `intent.putExtra(String, Serializable)` or `intent.putExtra(String, Parcelable)`. In your second activity you can get the object and display your data in your Activity. Have a look at the below links :

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html